# How to create custom FormField initialize with object?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a `DatePicker` widget to select between a start and end date; these fields are stored in a `DateRange` class.  When initializing the form field, I also need to initialize the DateRange object so that I may access both the start and end date fields. However, since it is a custom object, I am not able to initialize the `initialValue` field in the `FormField` constructor. Is there a way for me to initialize so that it gets assigned to the `initialValue` before calling the superclass?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DateRange {
  DateTime start;
  DateTime end;

  DateRange({this.start, this.end});
}

class DatePicker extends FormField<DateRange> {
  final ValueChanged<DateRange> onChanged;

  DatePicker(
    BuildContext context, {
    Key key,
    FormFieldSetter<DateRange> onSaved,
    FormFieldValidator<DateRange> validator,
    this.onChanged,
    DateRange initialValue,   /// I would like to do: initialValue = DateRange(), but it doesn't work.
    bool autovalidate = false,
    bool enabled = true,
  }) : super(
    onSaved: onSaved,
    validator: validator,
    initialValue: initialValue,
    autovalidate: autovalidate,
    enabled: true,
    builder: (FormFieldState<DateRange> state) {
      return Container();    /// Where the implementation is
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options that I see, but one of them may not work depending on your implementation.

Option 1 - Create the `DateRange` in the initializer list instead:

```dart
class DatePicker extends FormField<DateRange> {
  final ValueChanged<DateRange> onChanged;

  DatePicker(
    BuildContext context, {
    Key key,
    FormFieldSetter<DateRange> onSaved,
    FormFieldValidator<DateRange> validator,
    this.onChanged,
    DateRange initialValue,
    bool autovalidate = false,
    bool enabled = true,
  }) : super(
    onSaved: onSaved,
    validator: validator,
    initialValue: initialValue ?? DateRange(),
    autovalidate: autovalidate,
    enabled: true,
    builder: (FormFieldState<DateRange> state) {
      return Container();
    });
}
```

Option 2 - Make `DateRange` a `const` constructor:

```dart
class DateRange {
  final DateTime start;
  final DateTime end;

  const DateRange({this.start, this.end});
}

class DatePicker extends FormField<DateRange> {
  final ValueChanged<DateRange> onChanged;

  DatePicker(
    BuildContext context, {
    Key key,
    FormFieldSetter<DateRange> onSaved,
    FormFieldValidator<DateRange> validator,
    this.onChanged,
    DateRange initialValue = const DateRange(),
    bool autovalidate = false,
    bool enabled = true,
  }) : super(
    onSaved: onSaved,
    validator: validator,
    initialValue: initialValue,
    autovalidate: autovalidate,
    enabled: true,
    builder: (FormFieldState<DateRange> state) {
      return Container();
    });
}
```

Either way, I can't really see a reason to do what you're asking. The `initialValue` parameter should be allowed to be `null`(so no default value should be assigned) and the user of `DateRange` should be given full control over it. If your application is better/has cleaner code with this implementation you can of course keep it this way.

Comment: The reason why I want to initialize `DateRange` if the `initialValue` is null is because I need to access the start and end variable of `DateRange` inside my implementation so that I can avoid calling those fields on an uninitialized `DateRange`. Thanks for the solution.